# most efficient way of implementing _mm256_mask_add_ps on avx2

Tags: x86-64, avx2

Unfortunately AVX2 does not have mask registers. What should I do if I want to accomplish `_mm256_mask_add_ps`? Is there a way to do it without unpacking said mask into epi8 registers or the like?

Comment: Get your mask a vector, and `_mm256_and_ps` one of the inputs to addition. ([is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675)).  If you're generating the mask with `_mm256_cmp_ps` near where you're using it, don't `_mm256_movemask_ps` in the first place, just use the SIMD compare mask.

Comment: And no, there's no way to use an integer bitmap to control a vector operation until AVX-512; as you say that's the whole point of mask registers, a new capability in AVX-512.

Comment: Typo: "Get your mask *as* a vector"...  Also, found a 128-bit example of compare / AND / add: [Trying to add an \_\_m128 using an and mask in SSE programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15808565)