# How to avoid the if condition branch?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I want to use sse to optimize the c++ code, but I meet a situation that has two double loops in a function, the orginal code:

```
double eval_pef(int n, int delta, double mass, double grav, double sep,
                double fcon, double *x, double *y, double *z, double *fx,
                double *fy, double *fz) {
  double pe, rlen, xdiff, ydiff, zdiff, vmag;
  int nx, ny, dx, dy,index;

  pe = 0.0;
  // loop over particles
    for (nx = 0; nx < n; nx++) {
      for (ny = 0; ny < n; ny++) {
        index  =nx * n + ny;
      fx[index] = 0.0;
      fy[index] = 0.0;
      fz[index] = -mass * grav;
      // loop over displacements
      for (dy = MAX(ny - delta, 0); dy < MIN(ny + delta + 1, n); dy++) {
        for (dx = MAX(nx - delta, 0); dx < MIN(nx + delta + 1, n); dx++) {
          // exclude self interaction
          if (nx != dx || ny != dy) {
            // compute reference distance
            rlen =
                sqrt((double)((nx - dx) * (nx - dx) + (ny - dy) * (ny - dy))) *
                sep;
          
            // compute actual distance
            xdiff = x[dx * n + dy] - x[index];
            ydiff = y[dx * n + dy] - y[index];
            zdiff = z[dx * n + dy] - z[index];
            vmag = sqrt(xdiff * xdiff + ydiff * ydiff + zdiff * zdiff);
  
            // potential energy and force
            pe += fcon * (vmag - rlen) * (vmag - rlen);
            fx[index] += fcon * xdiff * (vmag - rlen) / vmag;
            fy[index] += fcon * ydiff * (vmag - rlen) / vmag;
            fz[index] += fcon * zdiff * (vmag - rlen) / vmag;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0.5 * pe;
}
```

One way is to use logic comparison in sse2

```
__m128d compare_result = _mm_cmplt_pd(vmag, rball_value);
 __m128d new_x = _mm_add_pd(xball_value,x_r_v);
new_x = _mm_or_pd(_mm_and_pd(compare_result, new_x),_mm_andnot_pd(compare_result, x_values));
```

Is there any other way to avoid such case?

Comment: I think it should be my modified version that reduces the number of effective iterations in the internal loop. AHHHH, life is so hard...

Comment: Why you use macroses and non-local iteration variables... that defeatssome optimization...

Comment: All your vectors are set from `_mm_set1_pd` so they have the same value in both elements, unless there's one I'm not seeing.  If so, that's pointless, you're doing the same computations twice, not operating on two different values in parallel.  e.g. you might start with a vector of `_mm_setr_pd(0.0, 1.0)` and add the initial `dx` value, so you're doing `dx` and `dx+1` in the two elements.  You'd need to adjust the loop conditions (and preferably change that to integer, not also doing the same work with scalar FP increments), like `for(i = 0 ; i < n - (simd_width - 1) ; i++)`.

Comment: Also, instead of doing expensive checks inside the loop for comparing an element to itself, maybe loop over where you store the results and zero out that diagonal, or something like that, if that's possible.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie  HAHAHA, that's right, but the most troublesome thing is that I know my code is slightly stupid, but I don't know where it is...

Comment: @PeterCordes thankyou. I have changed the way of initialing ny dy by _mm_setr_pd, because both of them are increased by 2. But now rlen get a NAN, I think your words make sense, is there a problem with my understanding, btw I have updated the sse version and output.

Comment: You tagged this [hpc], but you're talking about using SSE2 specifically.  HPC on x86 these days should be using at least AVX (`__m256d` 32-byte vectors of 4 doubles), or AVX-512 with 256 or 512-bit vectors.  Of course, 2-element vectors might be a good starting point to figure out your algorithm.  Also, don't use `std::endl`; you can just use `<< '\n'` which is exactly equivalent except for not forcing a slow flush of the stream, which you don't need for debug prints unless something is crashing.  Also, surely your real code doesn't just print, so where *do* you store the results?

Comment: You're doing `__m128d ny_value = _mm_setr_pd(ny,ny+1);` *and* `__m128d dy_value = _mm_setr_pd(dy,dy+1);`, so you're trying to vectorize over both loops at once.  Often you just vectorize over one of the loops, and maybe unroll over others.  This code is messy and hard to read, especially with bad indenting and no idea of the scalar types, and has stray stuff like updating `fx[index]` which seems unrelated to the computation you're asking about.  Also not totally clear what the results are supposed to mean, like distances of x,y grid coordinates in a square around a set in a range?

Comment: @PeterCordes  I'm sorry for error tag. I did that becuase this is an assignment of HPC course. I have removed it. And I use rlen to calculate the new PE.

Comment: "PE" doesn't mean anything to me, except maybe "potential energy".  But IDK why this computation would give a potential energy.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right. It's potential energy. I have complete the core function in original and sse2 version, it's more clear now. And thank you very much for seeing now...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry my original code was difficult to read, but I tried another way to optimize it using sse2. The most important thing is actually how to eliminate if conditional branches, not the problem of sse2.

```
v_pe = _mm_mul_pd(v_fcon,_mm_mul_pd(v_term, v_term));
_mm_storeu_pd(pe_vals, v_pe);
if (dx == nx && dy == ny){
     pe_vals[0] = 0;
}
if ((dx == nx && dy+1 == ny)|| dy + 1 == MIN(ny + delta + 1, n) ){
     pe_vals[1] = 0;
}
pe += pe_vals[0] + pe_vals[1];
```

Comment: Handle the final element outside the loop instead of using `MIN`.  You can conditionally zero something with `_mm_cmpeq_epi64` or `_mm_and_pd` to get a mask of all-zero / all-one bits, which you can use with `_mm_and_pd` or `_mm_andnot_pd` to either keep or zero the corresponding element of `pe_vals`.  With two conditions together, you can `_mm_and_pd` or `_mm_or_pd` two compare masks together to only zero where both true or neither true.

Comment: Also, don't do `pe += pe_vals[0] + pe_vals[1];` inside the loop; use `_mm_add_pd` into a vector, and horizontal sum it to scalar outside the loop.

Comment: See [Conditional SSE/AVX add or zero elements based on compare](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49982536) for an example.  (That uses `_ps` vectors with 32-bit elements; using `_pd` for everything works the same way, except when mixing with 32-bit integer elements of course.)

Comment: Also, this seems like a new question, not an answer to your existing question.  And BTW, a more efficient strategy might be to just go down the "diagonal" where `nx == dx && dy == ny` and subtract those elements where you added a value you shouldn't have.  (Unless that value can be huge or NaN, in which case you need to avoid adding it in the first place because of rounding error or NaN.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I have tried this writing method before, like this new_x = _mm_or_pd(_mm_and_pd(compare_result, new_x),_mm_andnot_pd(compare_result, x_values)); But finnally I gave it up, becase in my case, there are quite a few areas where I need to use comparision results, and I think the current approach is clearer. And I don't know if it's because comparison results relates to the for loop parameters, I always don't get the correct results. Maybe there's still a problem with my writing method.

Comment: @PeterCordes Got it.

Comment: @PeterCordes  Your previous comment including `_mm_setr_pd(0.0, 1.0)`has solved the problem of print NAN or rounding error. And I have updated the problem yet,  cuz the new question is the one I do really want to ask. Thank you so much for helping me a lot.

Comment: You don't need to blend with `or(and,andnot)`, you just need to zero something or not.  The bit-pattern for `0.0` is all-zero bits, so you can AND with a mask to leave something zeroed or unchanged.  Like in [Trying to add an \_\_m128 using an and mask in SSE programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15808565) / [SSE comparison returns vector of NANs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57091959)

Answer (score 0):

As with anything, benchmark to to understand if the conditional:

```
if (nx != dx || ny != dy) {
```

Is actually slowing anything down.

With full compiler optimizations on (i.e. -O3), benchmark the code as you have it.   (e.g. call the function 100000 times with a large array and measure how long it takes).  Repeat several times to account for variances.

Then benchmark with the condition removed. The latter will be an incorrect program, but if the subsequent benchmark isn't any faster, then eliminating the condition won't be helpful.

If you are able to prove eliminating the condition is valuable, you could do this:

Replace this line (and it's closing curly brace)

```
if (nx != dx || ny != dy) {
```

With this:

```
int t = (nx != dx || ny != dy); // t will be either 1 or 0
```

Then when you compute the result in each loop, apply t as a multiplier:

```
        pe += t * (fcon * (vmag - rlen) * (vmag - rlen));
        fx[index] += t * (fcon * xdiff * (vmag - rlen) / vmag);
        fy[index] += t * (fcon * ydiff * (vmag - rlen) / vmag);
        fz[index] += t * (fcon * zdiff * (vmag - rlen) / vmag);
```

Such that if `t == 0`, then the additions to `pe`, `fx`, `fy`, and `fz` will alse amount to zero. As if it was never called.

I have no idea if this will speed things up, but it's something you can try and benchmark.

My initial guess would be that the `sqrt` statements are where the code is going to spend most of its time and these micro-optimizations won't matter.